# Jquery onclick remove corresponding line

Tags: jquery, events

The problem is that when I click on the delete button it removes all content and not just the corresponding line.

```js
$("a.boutonsupr").live("click",function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   if(confirm("You want to delete the image ?")) {
    this.click;
    
   $(".box li").fadeOut('slow', function(){
     $(this).remove();
  });

   }
   else
   {
   
   }       
   event.preventDefault();
   
});
```

```css
.box li{
   border-width:1px;
 border-style:dotted;
 border-color:black;
 background-color:blue;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 color:white;
}
ul li a{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box">
  <li> 
  <a class="boutonsupr" href=""><span >remove</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="boutonsupr" href=""><span >remove</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="boutonsupr" href=""><span >remove</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="boutonsupr" href=""><span >remove</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS FIDDLE :**

https://jsfiddle.net/x7g7gpwp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's removing everything because the selector you're using, `.box li` will target all matching elements. Instead, you need a selector more specific to the clicked element. Something like this should do it..

```
$("a.boutonsupr").on("click",function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  if(confirm("You want to delete the image ?")) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, don't use `live`, it was deprecated many years ago.. You should use `on`. I also removed the empty else statement and `this.click`, as this doesn't make sense, assuming you meant to call `click()` but this would just result in an endless loop, as it stands its just a reference to a nonexistent property.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  So you don't want to requery, you need to know what was clicked.

you want to use "this" inside the function to reference the a tag.

The parent property references the li.  So, that's what you want to call the fade out and removal on.

```
$("a.boutonsupr").live("click",function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   if(confirm("You want to delete the image ?")) {
    this.click;

    var li = $(this).parent();
    li.fadeOut('slow', function(){
             li.remove();
  });

   }
   else
   {

   }       
   event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: NP...If it works...please use green checkbox to accept

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector choose all the element with that class to remove.
try this

```
$(this).parents('li').fadeOut
```

jsfiidle Example

https://jsfiddle.net/Not2Day2Die/L41gcxkb/

Hope this answer help u :) .